# How can I use VBA coding to make word automatically remember the filename of a dragged and dropped image?

Tags: vba, image, ms-word, filenames

I have tried to drag and drop an image into MS Word that should contain the filename without displaying it on screen. Then when a macro is run using Alt+F8 it should retrieve the filename.
Can you please help me by viewing below or coming up with alternative solutions? It could really help me a lot when a teacher wants a file represented in a report afterwards.

I have tried to do it using the following macros inserted as modules:

```
Option Explicit

' Enable dropped images
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl)
    ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:="", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
End Sub

' Capture the filename when an image is dropped
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
    If ContentControl.Title = "MyImageControl" Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ImageFilename").Range.Text = ContentControl.Range.InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.SourceFullName
    End If
End Sub

' Retrieve the image filename from the bookmark
Sub RetrieveImageName()
    Dim imageName As String
    imageName = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ImageFilename").Range.Text
    MsgBox "Image Name: " & imageName, vbInformation, "Image Information"
End Sub
```

Comment: The code in your question is for Excel, not Word.

Comment: Arh you are right! Embarassing, I will edit the question right away

Comment: `InlineShapes(1).LinkFormat.SourceFullName` would only have a value if the shape contained a linked image, which it doesn’t as you dragged and dropped the image. Given that a copy of that image is stored in the Word file, why would Word need the original filename?

Comment: Simply change LinkToFile:=False to LinkToFile:=True

Comment: Thank you for your responses! @macropod it does not seem to work. I get a "run-time error 5941: The requested member of the collection does not exist."

Comment: Well, presumably, you're also supplying a filename for the insertion. The code you posted merely has FileName:="". That would likely cause an error regardless of what you have for LinkToFile:=. The LinkToFile:=True directive is needed for you to be able to retrieve the filename at a later time. Either way, though, you *must* supply one for AddPicture to work.